# correct usage of scala map

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I find myself using the Scala map function on Option values as follows:

```
optionVal.map( val => {
  doSomethingWith(val)
  doSomethingElseWith(val)
  // etc. (an example could be executing a database query)
})
```

where optionVal could be for instance:

```
Option[String]
```

In other words, I am using it as a way to ensure that the Option is populated with something, and if so to execute a block of statements.

It seems a bit odd and convoluted to me coming from the Java world where would just do an if check on the object (`if (someObject != null) { // execute statements}` ).  Also it seem like it *may* not be semantically what the map function was intended to do, even though it works. So I wanted to check if this is the proper / idiomatic way to do this in Scala.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `doSomethingwith(value)` returns `Unit`, then you can use `foreach`:

```
def doSomethingWith(value: Int): Unit = println(value)

val opt: Option[Int] = Some(1)

opt.foreach{ value =>
    doSomethingWith(value)  // prints the value
}

val noOpt: Option[Int] = None 

noOpt.foreach{ value =>
    doSomethingWith(value)   // Does nothing, because noOpt is empty.
}
```

If you intend to map (to return it in some way) the value inside the `Option`, then continue using `map`.

Mapping an `Option` to `Unit` is harmless, but it would make your code more readable to use `foreach`.

Comment: Or `for (value <- opt) doSomethingWith(value)` which (to my eyes) is more readable still. Use `yield` if `doSomethingWith` does return something useful

Answer (score 0):

@LimbSoup's answer is definitely appropriate for a case where you're simply calling a side-effectful function with no return type. For the sake of completeness, here are few other ways to work with Option values in Scala. When working with functions that return a value, you've correctly identified one of the more idiomatic methods, using the `map` function:

```
val optX : Option[Int] = Some(1)
optX map { _ + 1 }    // returns Some[Int](2)

val optY : Option[Int] = None
optY map { _ + 1 }    // returns None
```

This behavior extends to other functions like `filter` and `fold`. As syntactic sugar, you can also use a `for` comprehension, the same way you would on a list.

```
for (x <- optX) yield (x + 1)  // desugars to 'optX.map(_ + 1)'
for (x <- optX) doSomething(x) // desugars to 'optX.foreach(x => doSomething(x))'
```

If you want to use Options a bit more in the vein of how you would in Java, you would typically write a pattern matching statement, as follows:

```
optX match {
  case Some(x) => doSomething(x)
  case None    => doSomethingElse()
}
```

This is good for when you want an if/else sort of behavior, rather than executing or not executing a function based on whether or not you have a value.

When working with a sequence of Options, you can strip out the `None` values by using `flatMap`.

```
// Applies a map to only the types with values
Seq(Some(1), Some(2), Some(3), None, None, None, Some(4)) flatMap { _ + 1 }  // returns Seq(2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Lastly, you can completely throw caution to the wind and call `.get` on your Option type. You probably *shouldn't*, but it's available to you. This will either return the unwrapped value, in case of a 'Some', or throw an exception in case of 'None'.